# Symfony with Twig: access another config value using globals

Tags: symfony, twig

i want to display in one template partial information from my doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        servicename:  'myServiceName'
```

i already used twig globals in the past and it works well. For this case, I have tried something like this :

```
twig:

    globals:
        app_doctrine_servicename: '%doctrine.dbal.servicename%'
```

and display `{{app_doctrine_servicename}}` in my template but it doesn't work, i have an error.

I saw it is possible to access services directly from twig but i would like to avoid this approach and display only this specific param string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*i have an error*" - What error? Please include all details inside your question

Comment: One thing to understand is that Symfony does not maintain an array of all configuration.   The config files are processed during the compile phase and then discarded.  So if a particular value is not explicitly set as a parameter then the value is not available during runtime.  In any event the answer below should get you where you want to be.  dbal.servicename is not often used.  I guess you are connecting to an Oracle database.

Comment: @Cerad yes. But the doctrine servicename was just one of the config info i wanted to retrieve. I have also api endpoints that are differents per environment, etc ...

Comment: It is what is is.  The full configuration is not available at runtime.  I suppose you could read the config file directly but that has many downsides.  If a particular bundle does not expose the configuration you want then that is a pretty strong indication that you probably should not be doing that.  Might be time for an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

Services defined in your YAML should start with `@`.

Check the console for the correct service definition:

```
bin/console debug:container
```

If you do not want the service, but only the value of `servicename` you should probably set that value in a separate parameter so you can add it in various locations:

```yaml
parameters:
    dbal_servicename: 'myServiceName'

doctrine:
    dbal:
      servicename: "%dbal_servicename%"

twig:
    globals:
        app_doctrine_servicename: "%dbal_servicename%"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is precisely what I am trying to avoid: defining informations that are already defined somewhere else, thus, increasing the risk to not synchronize them correctly.